# Prefabs don't sync for different players

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Bullet prefab with *Network Transform* and *Network Identity*.

> Player script for spawn bullet:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    bool ready = true;
    public Transform firePoint;
    public bool shot;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) || shot)
        {
            if (ready)
            {
                Shoot();
            }
            else
            {
                // click sound
            }
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        ready = false;
        var bulletGo = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        LeanTween.delayedCall(6f, () => { ready = true; });
    }
}
```

But when I shoot, my enemy don't see this bullet.
Why it doesn't sync? My player also has *Network Transform* and *Network Identity*, and all is ok.

Comment: Did you register the bullet prefab in the NewtorkManager? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html

Comment: Ok, I registered it, but anyway it doesn't work

Comment: Ok. Then maybe you need to tell Unity's network server to actually spawn it. Use this: 
`var bulletGo = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
NetworkServer.Spawn(bulletGo);`

Comment: It works! Ty. Also now I need to reslove next problem - one player can't destroy stone (map part), but second player can destroy stones, and this stones won't be destroyed on first player's screen (what?)

Comment: Are the stones networked objects too (with NetowkIdentity behaviour)? If so, similar to how you would spawn a networked object you may need to use `NetworkServer.Destroy(gameObject)` to destroy the object for all clients.

This might be the topic of another question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spawn a networked object Unity provides a specific function `NetworkServer.Spawn` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer.Spawn.html)

This function needs to be called after you instantiate an object so that all the clients spawn it in their scene.

In your case, after you instantiate your `bulletGo` object you should call:

```
NetworkServer.Spawn(bulletGo)
```